# CSS position change on image next to it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So, I have the same image that I need to overlap each other. The first one as you can see has an z-index:1 and the others of 0. But, as the images keep repeating I have to keep creating a new style to make the next one 115px to the right. Is there a css pseudo method to automate this or do I have to revert to using jquery or js to bump it to the right?

```
<style>
img.overlap{z-index:1;position:absolute;left:670px;}
img.underlap{z-index:0;position:absolute; left:785px;}
</style>

<div class="span12">
     <a href="#"><img src="img/blue_btn.png" alt="Home" class="overlap"/></a>
     <a href="#"><img src="img/blue_btn.png" alt="About" class="underlap"/></a>
     <a href="#"><img src="img/blue_btn.png" alt="Services" class="underlap"/></a>
     <a href="#"><img src="img/blue_btn.png" alt="Portfolio" class="underlap"/></a>
     <a href="#"><img src="img/blue_btn.png" alt="Blog" class="underlap"/></a>
     <a href="#"><img src="img/blue_btn.png" alt="Contact" class="underlap"/></a>
</div>
```

UPDATE: I was cropping the image as I read this post as I knew that it would be hard to visualize. Here is the nav area. I have cropped the first one and I will repeat them and later change the alpha with jquery.

http://weslice.com/images/nav_complete.jpg

Comment: Now sure what you mean here. Can you post a diagram?

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of this? Can you post an example on jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/2vUzp/9/ achieves the effect without the need for classes (though it does reverse the order of the menu in the html, but not in what is displayed to the average user). After looking at your sample image, you may not want the "hover" effect in my example, but that can be removed.

CSS

```
.span12 {
    float: left;
}

.span12 a {
    position: relative;
    margin-right: -30px;
    display: block;
    float: right;
}

.span12 a:first-child {
    margin-right: 0;
}

.span12 a:hover {
    z-index: 1;
}

.span12 img { /*for demo*/
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 20px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    background-color: cyan;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="span12">
     <a href="#"><img src="img/blue_btn.png" alt="Contact"/></a>
     <a href="#"><img src="img/blue_btn.png" alt="Blog"/></a>
     <a href="#"><img src="img/blue_btn.png" alt="Portfolio"/></a>
     <a href="#"><img src="img/blue_btn.png" alt="Services"/></a>
     <a href="#"><img src="img/blue_btn.png" alt="About" /></a>
     <a href="#"><img src="img/blue_btn.png" alt="Home" /></a>
</div>
```

Comment: this solution worked 100% as well as the others but the container is now floating flush. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You should try using float and margins instead of absolute positioning.

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp

Comment: Hi Ryan,Thanks for the response unfortunately float won't work here as I'm trying to overlap the previous image. I have posted an example image so we can all learn what css technique we can use next time this arises from designers creating crazy mockups. :)

Comment: Please try to avoid linking to w3schools. [This site](http://w3fools.com/) explains why better than I can in this short space

Answer (score 2):

How about using `display : inline-block` to get your elements to sit next to each-other, then use `margin : -*px` to overlap the elements:

```
.span12 a {
    display : inline-block;
    margin  : 0 0 0 -20px;/*this margin is responsible for the overlap between elements*/
    
    /*IE 6&7 Compatibility*/
    *display : inline;/*only read by IE7*/
    zoom     : 1;/*give the element the `hasLayout` property since you can't give it to an element directly*/
    _height  : 50px;/*only read by IE6, but is necessary to specify a height for IE6*/
}
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/WJKS5/2/

### Update

To stack the element from left to right instead of right to left:

```
.span12 a {
    float  : right;
    margin : 0 -10px 0 0;/*this margin is responsible for the overlap between elements*/
}
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/WJKS5/4/

Comment: This does not have the images overlapping from left to right (left on top), but rather from right to left.

Comment: @ScottS That's a good point, see this updated JSFiddle that uses `float : right` to stack from the left to the right: http://jsfiddle.net/WJKS5/4/

Comment: This seems like the solution but, I get a huge gap to the left of the elements. http://weslice.com/lit/index.html

Comment: `float: right` is what I used in my solution :-). Only you need to reorder your source html to make it work right, and then you would have my solution.

Comment: @MIguel Set the width of the container element to the width of the child elements combined minus the number of elements time the margin used.

Comment: @MIguel and Jasper--there is no need for any math to get the container wrap. See my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to accomplish an overlap, floating's probably not going to work. I would recommend you use CSS sibling selectors and write rules specifically for 'img', 'img + img', 'img + img + img', etc. that would increase incrementally.  I think that should be the only pure CSS way around it. Doing this with JavaScript would be a breeze.

Comment: Keep in mind that the sibling selector isn't fully supported in Internet Explorer versions before 9. And the overlap makes it more difficult, but can still be done with CSS and float using containers and absolutely positioning the content in the overlap element.

Comment: @RyanP The adjacent sibling selector (`+`) is available in IE 7+: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel2

Comment: @Jasper I said "fully supported." In IE7, the sibling selector works on page load, but not for changes after load. In IE8, elements don't update until focus changes. IE9 fully supports the sibling selector.

Comment: @RyanP I don't see either of those issues when viewing this test page in IE7 or IE8: http://jsfiddle.net/6jyz3/2/. I'd like to be aware of any issues that do exist, so am I looking at this incorrectly?